# XGBOOST: Cannot flip the axis' of importance-Features plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, xgboost

I am trying to **flip** the axis so the **`Features`** be on the X axis. Following code gives me an error that the system overwrites the axis'.

```
    >gplt = xgb.ggplot.importance (importance_matrix = xgb.importance(model =model_xgb) , top_n = 10 , n_clusters = 1 ) 
                                                   +theme(legend.position = "none" , text = element_text(size = 20))

    >gplt +coord_flip()


    #[OUTPUT]:

    Coordinate system already present. Adding new coordinate system, which will replace the existing one.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the code for `xgb.ggplot.importance`, you'll see it contains a call to `coord_flip`, and calling it twice won't change anything. To get what you want, you can do

```
gplt + coord_cartesian()
```

you'll still see the message but your axes should be flipped.